# Reload page after second click on routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

This question has already asked.
When we click the second time on a link like that `<a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>`, the page does not reload.

[Angular2 Router3 - Can't reload/refresh active route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036498/angular2-router3-cant-reload-refresh-active-route)

[Angular 2 reloads routerLink user clicks again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186614/angular-2-reloads-routerlink-user-clicks-again)

But it has been solved when angular 2 was in beta version and there was an angular issue regarding the question.

Now that we have angular 4, I will ask if the answers provided are still the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was curious and did some googling on my own. I found this workaround on a GitHub feature request for Angular:

```
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
    return false;
};

this._router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this._router.navigated = false;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

I tried adding this to my **app.component.ts** `ngOnInit` function, and it sure worked. All further clicks on the same link now reloads the `component` and data.

[Link to original GitHub feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831)

Credit goes to **mihaicux2** on GitHub.

I tested this on version `4.0.0-rc.3` with `import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: @ArgOn, Thanks for this response!